# how to insert a column between columns in vba even if cells are locked

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert a new column between columns and it worked using the code below:

```
   Columns("G:G").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

However, if I am going to lock the sheet, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Lock-cells-to-protect-them-54fedd95-28dc-4abc-a26c-6566917c1a59, I receive an error if I am going to execute the code.

I am using VBA anyway. Does anybody know?

Comment: You need to unprotect the sheet first

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this using the code in vba? I really need to protect the data..;( thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unprotect the sheet

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    Columns("G:G").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="password"
End Sub
```

Comment: do you know how to allow deleting of column to this column? Since, deleting is locked.. thanks

Comment: You mean besides unprotecting the sheet?